# Что значит аннотация @RequestApi

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

Метод помеченный аннотацией `@RequestApi` не выполнится?

Например в методе есть блок кода который выполняется на Android старше 5.0, а приложение имеет `minSdk = 4.0 android`. В название метода добавляется аннотация.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Офф. документация сообщает:

> Denotes that the annotated element should only be called on the given API level or higher. This is similar in purpose to the older `@TargetApi` annotation, but more clearly expresses that this is a requirement on the caller, rather than being used to "suppress" warnings within the method that exceed the `minSdkVersion`.

Перевод:

> Обозначает, что аннотированный элемент должен вызываться только на данном уровне API или выше. Это похоже на более старую аннотацию `@TargetApi`, но более четко выражает, что это требование для вызывающей стороны, а не используется для «подавления» предупреждений в методе, который превышает `minSdkVersion`.